# How to visualize the amount of changes in the video on a timeline?

Tags: video, visualization

In a security camera footage pointed to a building door, the vast majority of frames are practically identical to their previous frame.

I'd like to have some timeline view which can graph the amount of change, so that I can easily navigate and inspect those parts of the video in which there was substantial movement (and then understand if it was benevolent or not...)

What tool can allow me to generate such a timeline graph? Ideally it should integrated with a video player so that I can click some spike in the graph and instantly see the frame there.

Comment: Can you get hold of a MATLAB license? I might have some code that basically does most of this work already. Although there should be security / surveillance software that is already made for this pretty common task.

Answer (score 0):

If under GNU/Linux, you might want to have a look at [motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) which can automatically deal with motion events.  You won't get a timeline graph, but I guess you won't need it anymore :)